# Android: The Constructor is undefined?

Tags: android, sqlite, constructor

In the following activity (SQLite databaseHelper class) I am getting the error:

```
The Constructor Score(String, int, int, long) is undefined
```

The problem has started when I added a new instance var into my Score class. This is the object into which I will be inserting to my DB.

Its constructor and inst vars now are as follows:

```
package com.example.brianapp;

import java.io.Serializable;

//note: serializable was imported to attempt to pass an object from mediation and meditationresults
public class Score implements Serializable {
    String name;
    int meditation;
    int max;
    int score;
    long date;

    public Score() {

    }

    public Score(String name, int meditation, int max, int score, long date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.meditation = meditation;
        this.max = max;
        this.score=score;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

The code block in which I am getting the syntax error in the database Helper class is:

```
/**
     * Method will return a single Name and score
     * 
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    // Getting single contact
    Score getScore(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SCORE, new String[] { COL_NAME,
                COL_MED, COL_MAX, COL_SCORE, COL_DATE }, COL_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null,null,null,null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Score score = new Score(cursor.getString(0),Integer.parseInt(cursor
                .getString(1)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)), cursor.getLong(4));
        // return contact
        return score;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: instead of constructor use getters and setters

Comment: as far as i can see, it looks ok, is there any other place where you are using the constructor?

Comment: Can you post the actual error? Are you sure you imported the right Score class?

Comment: I think problem in eclipse, sometimes its not saving files so just hit `Ctrl+S` , close files in editor section and re-open it. Hope your problem will be resolve.

Comment: This is not the code that produces the error. Try cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: This code cannot produce this error. The function call has 3 ints, the error has only 2. We cannot debug code we cannot see.